# Webview javascript not working in samsung glaxy tab version 4.4

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have and issue to load webpage in webview but javascript code in that web page is not working but working in most of mobiles devices.
Samsung glaxy tab detail
Api level 19 tablet android 4.4.4.

here is my code:

```
webView.
    setWebViewClient(new MyBroweser());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(
    WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.setClickable(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView.setNetworkAvailable(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: Whats the error (message)?

Comment: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(249)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addNumber is not defined", source:

Comment: this is the error when i click on web page in the webview

Comment: but when same web page load without webview in browser it works fine and other devices on webview it works fine but only in device APi 19 it doesnot work